# How to set tableview background color?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I know i am going to ask a silly question but please provide some answer.

If i have table view, I want to set background color of table view and i have a string named `color` which have the value as `"gray Color"`.

How to set background Color of table view with the help of string `color`.

For clarifications, Please get back to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of code you may use to get started. I used all the `UIColor's` class colors to keep code short and clean. If you need to determine other custom color names, like "gray Color" you were asking you'll be forced to write a long if clause with and if statement for each color you want to handle.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // statically add UIColor class names (for sake of simplicity)
    self.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"blackColor", 
                                            @"darkGrayColor",
                                            @"lightGrayColor",
                                            @"whiteColor",
                                            @"grayColor",
                                            @"redColor",
                                            @"greenColor",
                                            @"blueColor",
                                            @"cyanColor",
                                            @"yellowColor",
                                            @"magentaColor",
                                            @"orangeColor",
                                            @"purpleColor",
                                            @"brownColor",
                                            @"aColor",
                                            @"lightTextColor",
                                            @"darkTextColor",
                                            @"groupTableViewBackgroundColor",
                                            @"viewFlipsideBackgroundColor",
                                            @"scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor",
                                            @"underPageBackgroundColor",
                                            nil];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *colorName = [self.colors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    SEL colorSelector  = NSSelectorFromString(colorName);
    if ([UIColor respondsToSelector:colorSelector])
    {
        UIColor *cellColor = [UIColor performSelector:colorSelector];
        const CGFloat *componentColors = CGColorGetComponents(cellColor.CGColor);
        int numComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(cellColor.CGColor);

        // get inverse color for cell text 
        UIColor *inverseColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        if (numComponents == 4)
        {
            inverseColor = [[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:(255 - 255 * componentColors[0])
                                                  green:(255 - 255 * componentColors[1])
                                                   blue:(255 - 255 * componentColors[2])
                                                  alpha:componentColors[3]] autorelease];            
        } else if (numComponents == 2) {
            inverseColor = [[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:(255 - 255 * componentColors[0])
                                                   green:(255 - 255 * componentColors[0])
                                                    blue:(255 - 255 * componentColors[0])
                                                   alpha:componentColors[1]] autorelease];    
        }


        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = cellColor;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = inverseColor;
        cell.textLabel.text = colorName;

    } else {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];        
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unknown color (%@)", colorName];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;

    return cell;
}
```

[image: colored uitableview cells]

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color of UITableView in iPhone application, you just need to write the given line of code into the tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
 tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

//To Set Selected Background Color

```
UIImageView *selectedBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320,100)];
selectedBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackground];
```

For sample image....

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Unknown..I am asking if i have a string having color name then how to set that name to table background color. e g:I have string "color" whose value is "redColor".Can i set it as                                                                                tableView.backGroundColor=name;

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSDictionary class to store colors and string color will be key for color that you need i.e.

```
NSDictionary *colorsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               [UIColor redColor],@"Red Color",
                                               [UIColor greenColor],@"Green Color",
                                               [UIColor blueColor],@"Blue Color",nil];
tableView.backgroundColor = [colorsDict valueForKey:color];
```

String color must be equal to any key.